# String to Columns

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, dictionary, split

I have a **string** column in my df.

```
col
a: 1, b: 2, c: 3
b: 1, c: 3, a: 4
c: 2, b: 4, a: 3
```

I wish to convert this into multiple columns as:

```
a   b   c
1   2   3
4   1   3
3   4   2
```

Need help regarding this.

I am trying to convert this into a dict and then sort the dict. Post that, I want to maybe do a pivot table. Not exactly sure if it'll do but any help or better method will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension with double `split` by `,`  and `:`  for list of dictionaries and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dict(y.split(': ') for y in x.split(', ')) for x in df['col']],
                  index=df.index)
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  1  3
2  3  4  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
(df['col'].str.extractall('(\w+):\s*([^,]+)')
 .set_index(0, append=True).droplevel('match')[1]
 .unstack(0)
)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  1  3
2  3  4  2
```